# Regarding calling how many categories are in each table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a school type CMS system in php to get more experience.
I created a schedule.php page where it lists the school categories, for example:

Accounting
Biology
Math
Computer Science

I want to add put a number next to the category Accounting(2) coming from the database because there is 2 accounting classes.  for example Computer Science has 10 classes taught so it should be Computer Science(10)

My code only dispalys the name of the subject not the number of classes taught.

here is my code:

```
<?php


include('connect.php');

if(!isset($_GET['id']))
{
    ?>
    <table border="1" width="15%" height="137">
<tr>
    <td><?php

    //$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_name") or die(mysql_error());


    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(a.category_name, ' (', COUNT(b.category_id), ')') AS category
```

FROM categories a
LEFT JOIN classes b ON a.id = b.category_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.category_name") or die(mysql_error());

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query1))
    {
        print "<a href='schedule.php?id=" . $row->id .  "'>" . $row->category . "</a><br/>";
    } ?></td>
</tr>
```

```
    <?php


}
//if you click on the subject
else if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $category = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM classes WHERE category_id = " . $category;
    $query2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query2))
    {
    ?>

    <center><h3><?php echo $row->class_name . '-' . $row->units; ?>  </h3></center>
    <table border ="0" wdith="100%">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <strong>Description: </strong>
    <?php echo $row->class_description; ?>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table border="1" width="44%">
<tr>
    <td width="60"><b>Ticket</b> </td>
    <td width="123"><b>Days</b></td>
    <td width="120"><b>Hours</b></td>
    <td width="64"><b>Room</b></td>
    <td><b>Instructor</b></td>
</tr>


    <tr>
    <td width="60"> <?php echo $row->ticket; ?> </td>
    <td width="123"><?php echo $row->days; ?></td>
    <td width="120"><?php echo $row->start_hours . $row->time_format . '-' . $row->end_hours . $row->time_format2 ;  ?> </td>
    <td width="64"> <?php echo $row->room_number; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->instructor_name;  ?></td>
</tr>
```

```
    }//end while

}//end else if
```

?>

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing your DB schema, this question is very difficult to answer.

Comment: I have 2 tables in my database.  categories and classes table.  In categories table I have id 1 -> Accounting 2-> Computer Science ... In my classes table i have category_id, class_name-> Computer science 101, 102, etc...  How can I call a MYSQL query to display Computer Science(10)   Thanks.

Comment: @Masoman please post your database schema (name of your tables and columns) so we can give you an accurate answer. On what column is the classes table linked up to the categories table?

Comment: As a suggestion, you'll want to JOIN the two tables, GROUP BY category or category ID, and COUNT

Comment: my categories table ID int(11), category_name varchar(75).               my classes table I have category_id int(11), class_name var_char(75)  is this what you mean?  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your schema is along the lines of:

```
+---------------+     +--------------------+
| categories    |     | classes            |
+---------------+     +--------------------+
| ID            |     | id                 |
| category_name |     | category_id        |
| etc..         |     | etc...             |
+---------------+     +--------------------+
```

Where `classes.category_id` is a foreign key referencing `categories.id`, there is quite a simple solution:

```
SELECT a.ID, CONCAT(a.category_name, ' (', COUNT(b.category_id), ')') AS category
FROM categories a
LEFT JOIN classes b ON a.ID = b.category_id
GROUP BY a.ID, a.category_name
```

This will concatenate the count of classes to each category. Ex.

```
Biology (4)
Computer Science (10)
etc...
```

And you can simply reference the `category` column of the query in your PHP.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query1))
{
    print "<a href='schedule.php?id=" . $row->ID .  "'>" . $row->category . "</a><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Hi Zane,  I tried using the query above but it didnt work.  I am trying to understand this

Comment: Ok, your right it worked it listed Computer Science(10) Accounting(2), etc...  however i got these weird error stdClass::$id in C:\wamp\www\gcc\schedule.php on line 24.  Thanks.

Comment: @Masoman, can you post your entire code? Are you wanting to retrieve other columns other than the category's id, name, and count?

Comment: how can i post code in php format here?  so ill show you my whole code

Comment: @Masoman Just paste it in your question and do "code formatting" with the "`{ }`" button, or you could try [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com).

Comment: @Masoman, I had edited my answer a while back to include the "ID" column which you're missing. Use the updated query. Also use the updated code in the while loop.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks a lot Zane,  How can I get more experience with advanced queries.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be best to use a query with a join and group by clause. It might look like this:

```
SELECT 
    ca.*, 
    COUNT(cl.id) AS class_count 
FROM 
    categories ca 
    LEFT JOIN classes cl ON cl.category_id = ca.id 
GROUP BY ca.id
```